# Changing a Members variable value inside another classes function?

Tags: c++, class, console

I have been trying to make a texted based rpg game and have it so if you get a certain item it does certain things. Anyways what im trying to do is change a class variable from another classes function. how do I do this? I made up some sample code for you guys to look at exactly what im trying to do. There's no errors it just does not work. Thanks.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


// First class where we add values

class B
{
public:
    void AddValueB(int VALUE);
    int GetValueB(void);
    B();


private:
int value;;

};
// constructor
B::B(void)
{
    value=100;
}
// where we add the passed in value to our main value variable. 
void B::AddValueB(int VALUE)
{
    value+=VALUE;

}
// returns the final value
int B::GetValueB(void)
{
    return value;

}

//**Second Class**

class A
{
public:
    void SetValueA(int VALUE);
    int GetValueA(void);
    A();


private:
    int value;;

};
// constructor
A::A(void)
{

}
// sets value
void A::SetValueA(int VALUE)
{
    B b;
    value=VALUE;
// if value is one we pass 25 in B's AddValue() function which then should add 25 to the  value      variable. 
    if(value==1)
    {
        cout << "Should Be 125?\n\n";
        b.AddValueB(25);
    }
}
// returns value 
int A::GetValueA(void)
{
    return value;

}
//main
int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    // set A's value to 1 to trigger the if statement in the function which should add 25 to B's   value variable. 
    a.SetValueA(1);
    //output the final value for B.....still 100...why?
    cout << b.GetValueB();

    cin.get();

    return 0;


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `void A::SetValueA(int VALUE)`, you are creating a `B` on the stack and setting its value. It has no effect on the `B` created in `main`. If you want to set the value of `B` from `main` in `A::setValueA`, you have to pass it to the function.

First, change class interface

```
class A
{
public:
    void SetValueA(int VALUE, B& b);
    int GetValueA(void);
    A();


private:
    int value;;

};
```

Then, change the implementation.

```
void A::SetValueA(int VALUE, B& b)
{
    value=VALUE;
    if(value==1)
    {
        cout << "Should Be 125?\n\n";
        b.AddValueB(25);
    }
}
```

Then, change the call to `A::SetValueA` in `main`.

```
int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    a.SetValueA(1, b);
    cout << b.GetValueB();

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`friend` functions](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/813-friend-functions-and-classes/) could be useful, but if you are changing values from other classes it may be bad style.

```
class A
{
    private:
        // private stuff
    public:
        //public stuff
        friend class B
}

class B
{
    private:
        // private stuff
    public:
        //public stuff
        friend class A
}
```

Both classes then have direct access to each other's members.